# RDF file to java objects : DMOZ base

Tags: java, lucene, rdf

I'm using DMOZ as a document base and I'm trying to index it in order to execute
queries using Lucene. I'm guessing that I need to turn this RDF file into java 
objects. Is this the right way to do it? And if it is, how can I transform this file
to objects ?

This is an example of the RDF file :

```
<RDF>
<Topic>
    <catid>121212</catid>
    <link r:resource="http://page1.com"></link>
    <link r:resource="http://page2.com"></link>
    <link r:resource="http://page3.com"></link>
    <link r:resource="http://page4.com"></link>
</Topic>
<ExternelPage about="http://page1.com">
    <d:Title>the Title1</d:Title>
    <d:Description>description1</d:description>
    <ages>ages1</ages>
    <topic>topic1</topic>
</ExternelPage>
<ExternelPage about="http://page2.com">
    <d:Title>the Title2</d:Title>
    <d:Description>description2</d:description>
    <ages>ages2</ages>
    <topic>topic2</topic>
</ExternelPage>
<ExternelPage about="http://page3.com">
    <d:Title>the Title3</d:Title>
    <d:Description>description3</d:description>
    <ages>ages3</ages>
    <topic>topic3</topic>
</ExternelPage>
<ExternelPage about="http://page4.com">
    <d:Title>the Title4</d:Title>
    <d:Description>description4</d:description>
    <ages>ages4</ages>
    <topic>topic4</topic>
</ExternelPage>

<Topic>
    <catid>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</Topic>
<ExternelPage about="aLink">
    .
    .
    .

etc...
</RDF>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to parse the RDF file I would think, yes.  Seem to be a number of tools available for that purpose, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445/what-are-some-good-java-rdf-libraries   Exactly what you do with the data once you parse it depends on how you want it to be represented in the index (ie. how you want to be able to search it, etc)

Comment: Thanks, will look at these tools!

Answer (score 0):

Turning it into java classes is almost certainly not the right thing. RDF classes and java classes are for different things. Think of RDF classes more like database tables in a schema.